# hibernate join multiple tables and group condition

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have four tables as shown below. I would like to query by joining all these 4 tables and retrieve the email, registered date, last visit date, no of visits, and no Of times feedback provided and no of files uploaded.

```
Class User{
     int userId;
     String email;
     Date registeredDate;
     UserVisits userVisits; //one-to-one relation
     Set<UserFeedback> feedbacks; //one-to-many
     Set<UserUploads> uploads // one-to-many
}

Class UserVisits{
     int userId;
     Date lastVisited;
     int noOfVisits;
}

Class UserFeedback{
     int feedbackId;
     int userId;
     String feedback;
     Date feedbackDate
}

Class UserUploads{
      int fileId;
      User user;
      int fileName;
 }
```

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Sree

**EDIT**
My sql at the the looks like

```
select this_.email as email, this_.created_date as created_date,
userlogins1_.last_login as last_login, userlogins1_.login_count as login_count, 
fb_count, upload_count from user_details this_ 
left outer join user_logins userlogins1_ on this_.user_id=userlogins1_.user_id 
left outer join (select count(feedback_id) as fb_count, user_id 
from user_feedback group by user_id) as uf on this_.user_id=uf.user_id
left outer join (select count(uploadid) as upload_count, user_id 
from user_uploads group by user_id) as m on this_.user_id=m.user_id
order by this_.email asc
```

How would i use multiple sub queries like this?

**UPDATE. Have the solution but with a lil issue**

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class, "user");
criteria.createAlias("user.userLogins","userLogins",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);

DetachedCriteria fbCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserFeedback.class, "feedback");
fbCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("feedback.userId", "user.userId"));
fbCriteria.setProjection(Projections.alias(Projections.count("feedback.userId"), "fbcount"));
fbCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("fbcount"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(fbCriteria)); 

DetachedCriteria mapCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FileUploads.class, "uploads");
mapCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("uploads.user.userId", "user.userId"));
mapCriteria.setProjection(Projections.count("uploads.user.userId"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(mapCriteria)); 

List<User> users = criteria.list();
```

This returns what exactly I am looking for. I expect that for the rows with "`fbcount`" "`0`", to appear first when order in asc. but its happening. The rows with "`fbcount`" value "`0`" are always placed at end.

Please can anyone suggest me on how to achieve this.

Comment: I suggest that you start by reading a Hibernate/JPA tutorial, try to add the proper annotations on your own, and come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: David, whats is not specific for you in the above?

Comment: It's like you're asking: "How to use Hibernate?" Did you read about it before asking? What did you try so far? I don't mean to be rude, but the goal of a Q&A site is to help with specific questions/problems, not to teach broad topics or do the work for you. People will be more willing to help you if you show that you did some research by yourself before asking.

Comment: David, I have update with more clear n really seeking some help

Comment: Great, the quesion is more clear and specific now. Hopefully someone will know the answer.